How to understand why 2nd overtone with shorter wave length than 1st overtone has lower frequency
Please clarify the overtone frequency written in Music Theory: From Beginner to Expert - The Overtone Series & Just Intonation. Why the 2nd overtone with shorter wave length has lower frequency 660 Hz than the 1st overtone frequency 880 Hz?
As in the Fig 9 in the book the wavelength of the 2nd overtone is shorter than that of 1st. Hence, the frequency of 2nd should higher than 1st.



This (the shorter the length, the higher the frequency) is as explained in Modes on a String in YouTube.




However, the following sentences in the book says the 2nd overtone is 660 Hz which is less than that of 1st overtone 880 Hz. Yet, in the same sentences, it says the smaller the wavelength, the higher the frequency.



In the Fig 9, the wave length of the 2nd overtone (E5, Perfect 5th/7 semitones apart from A4) should have been longer than that of 1st overtone (A5, Perfect 8th/12 semitones apart from A4)?
(In the diagram, replace C with A, and others accordingly).




The second overtone is a perfect octave plus a fifth, so it would be E6 (1320Hz).  Everything else should check out after this adjustment.
You may have heard people describe the second overtone as simply being "the fifth" because any E is the fifth of a chord with root A, due to octave equivalency.  But to be precise, the second overtone is not a fifth above the fundamental, it is an octave plus a fifth, and your source does state this correctly (although the image caption could be clearer).

The author is numerically confused. He uses the expression "by a third" to mean "more or less anything where a 3 is involved". The "Second overtone" is an octave plus a fifth, and has a wavelength which is 1/3 of the fundamental; in careful writing this is "2/3 less" or "less by 2/3", not "less by a third". Then he asks "Which pitch is higher by a third...?" - which has no obvious meaning at all. (Normally "higher by a third" means higher by a musical interval of a third, which is completely different: actually a frequency ratio of 4:5 for a major third.) So ignore this bit, and press on: we get "interval between the second and third overtone". Um, no: this should be the interval between the second and third harmonics, or 1st and 2nd overtones. And it gets worse. It finally dawns on me: I think this "book" is fairly clearly AI-generated garbage. Throw it away.
Sorry, I didn't actually answer your question, but it should be obvious that the claim you find puzzling is false: a shorter wavelength always has a higher frequency.

In careful writing, one does not use "less" and "more" with multiplication but when indicating how much to add or subtract.  660 is 50% more than 440 or 1.5 times as large as (not 1.5 times greater than), and the wavelength of the third harmonic is 1/3 of the wavelength of the fundamental or as you note 2/3 smaller, not three times smaller.  Unfortunately, in the last couple of decades, this principle of careful writing has been increasingly ignored even in scientific usage.

The ancient Greeks had these ratios all worked out, although they might not have understood "frequency" and "wavelength" in the same way that we do: they are inverses of each other. But it appears that the author of the book is a human being,,, although the name "Nick Carter" is suspect.

@Wastrel: What's suspect about that name?!

@psmears  He's one of the Backstreet Boys.

@Wastrel: Sure, but "Nick" and "Carter" are both pretty common names, so it wouldn't be very remarkable for it to be a simple coincidence.
